# WebBrowser Control HtmlElement.SetAttribute not working with variables

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I'm facing a very weird issue, and I'm starting to think this is a bug somehow in .Net.

Issue is that whenever I use a string variable in a WebBrowserControl HtmlElement it simply doesn't work. But the same code with a static text works:

```
decimal a = 0.00000001m;
decimal b = 0.00000002m;
decimal rest = b - a;
string text = rest.ToString();

foreach (HtmlElement htmle in webBrowser1.Document.All)
{
    if (htmle.GetAttribute("name").Contains("valueMath"))
    {
        htmlElement.SetAttribute("value", text);    <----- Doesn't work
        //htmlElement.SetAttribute("value", "0.00000001");   <----- Works perfectly
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with .Net 4.5.

Thanks

Comment: What does mean `doesn't work`? Any error/exception?

Comment: The value is not set (no exceptions), instead the html element textBox is set with 0. I debuged already and on run time the variable has the correct string value... really weird

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the only bug I found was in my head :)

the issue was that this code was inside a foreach:

```
        decimal[] array= new decimal[5];

        array[0] = 0.00000001m;
        /*array[1] = 0.00000002m;
        array[2] = 0.00000003m;
        array[3] = 0.00000004m;
        array[4] = 0.00000005m;*/

        foreach (decimal a in array)
        {
              ...Code...
        }
```

The array value was being used in the setattribute, for testing I had the other 4 positions comments, but still the array had those arrays positions with zero.